# Running a git shell command on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, word-diff

I use git to compare strings (I've written why below). It works in development on my machine, but not on `Heroku`.

```
`git diff $(echo "hi" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo  "hello" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff`
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

Does anyone know how I can get this command working on `Heroku`? (btw the `usage:` hint doesn't fix the problem).

#### Update

Heroku support directed me to this [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) so that I can manually install git on their servers. The solution is in my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was:

#### Summary

First try `git init` in the Heroku console (step 5 & 6), maybe `git` is already installed. If not:

1. Install this [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt)
2. Add a `Aptfile (txt)` to the root, similar to a `Procfile`
3. Add latest `git` [source url](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/) to the `Aptfile`
4. Deploy
5. `heroku run rails c`
6. `` `git init` `` in the console

#### In more detail

1. Heroku directed me to this [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). Easy to install. But initially gave me this error, without too much explanation:

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

2. This was because I had not yet added an `Aptfile`, so do that before deploying because it won't work without. An `Aptfile` is just a `txt file` at the root of your `rails` app, like a `Procfile`. An empty `Aptfile` and a successful deployment. Now we have to add `git`.
3. Install the `git` by finding the latest version and copying the link from [this folder](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/) and adding it to your `Aptfile`. My `Aptfile` looks like this:

```
https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.25.0.tar.gz
```

4. Deploy, everything should be working.
5. Run `heroku run rails c`
6. Try the code below again and you'll notice you get a similar error:

```
`git diff $(echo "hi" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo  "hello" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff`
=> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
=> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
=> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
=> Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
=> Not a git repository
=> To compare two paths outside a working tree:
=> usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

7. But we now have `git` installed, so just make a repo:

```
`git init`
=> "Initialized empty Git repository in /app/.git/\n"
```

8. Success:

```
`git diff $(echo "hi" | git hash-object -w --stdin) $(echo  "hello" | git hash-object -w --stdin)  --word-diff`
=> "diff --git a/45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057 b/ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a\nindex 45b983b..ce01362 100644\n--- a/45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057\n+++ b/ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a\n@@ -1 +1 @@\n[-hi-]{+hello+}\n"
```

Hope this helps someone else.